# Dropping constraints in a PL/SQL loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get following error when I am attempting to disable constraints from hr.employees table

**Error:**

```
Error report -
ORA-02250: missing or invalid constraint name
ORA-06512: at line 14
02250. 00000 -  "missing or invalid constraint name"
*Cause:    The constraint name is missing or invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid identifier name for the constraint name.
```

Following is the code

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='EMPLOYEES';
    v_con_name VARCHAR2(20);
    SQL_STATMENT  VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
    SQL_STATMENT := 'ALTER TABLE HR.EMPLOYEES DISABLE CONSTRAINT :A';
    OPEN C1;
    LOOP
        FETCH C1 INTO v_con_name;
        EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STATMENT USING v_con_name;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_con_name);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
END;
/
```

When I comment following line

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STATMENT USING v_con_name;
```

Scripts execute successfully and provide following results

```
EMP_LAST_NAME_NN
EMP_EMAIL_NN
EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN
EMP_JOB_NN
EMP_SALARY_MIN
EMP_EMAIL_UK
EMP_EMP_ID_PK
EMP_DEPT_FK
EMP_JOB_FK
EMP_MANAGER_FK


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Hence I understand that the cursor construct is fetching the desired constraints name and also outside of this plsql  block, I could successfully alter employees table by disabling these constraints.

Please note that I have logged in as HR schema in Oracle 11g R2 XE database

I am not sure why I am getting the missing or invalid constraint name.. thanks to help me here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use bind variables for the names of database objects (or for DDL in general). You will need to build the entire ALTER statement by concatenating the name. Try something like this:

```
declare
    k_tablename constant user_constraints.table_name%type := 'EMPLOYEES';
begin
    for r in (
        select constraint_name
             , 'alter table ' || c.table_name || ' disable constraint ' || c.constraint_name as sql_statement
        from   user_constraints c
        where  table_name = k_tablename
    )
    loop
        execute immediate r.sql_statement;

        dbms_output.put_line('Disabled constraint ' || k_tablename || '.' || r.constraint_name);
    end loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I understood that I cannot use db objects in bind variable !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this script to generate the DISABLE script?

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';' STMNT
FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN
(SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P','U')
AND OWNER = 'HR'
AND TABLE_NAME IN
(
'EMPLOYEES'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler (& working) then the original attempt:

```
SQL> create table test (id number constraint pk_test primary key,
  2    ime varchar2(20) constraint ch_ime check (ime in ('little', 'foot')));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for c1 in (select table_name, constraint_name
  3               from user_constraints
  4               where table_name = 'TEST')
  5    loop
  6      execute immediate 'alter table ' || c1.table_name ||
  7                        ' disable constraint ' || c1.constraint_name;
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select constraint_name, status From user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                STATUS
------------------------------ --------
CH_IME                         DISABLED
PK_TEST                        DISABLED

SQL>
```